# How to use readline to insert a predetermined string onto the command line with a shortcut when using Bash?

Tags: command-line, bash

Is it possible to have an arbitrary amount of text placed next to the cursor on the command-line? I have heard that it is possible using Bash, but I am not sure how to accomplish it. It seems to be possible with readline, but the syntax of the shortcut seems to be rather obscure, as when I place it in my `~/.inputrc` and use the shortcut, nothing appears in the terminal. Can anyone explain the correct syntax of the entries in `~/.inputrc`?

Comment: Shift+Ctrl+C
Shift+Ctrl+V
Shift+Insert

Comment: Please show us what you tried.

Comment: @glennjackman Thanks, I've given an answer as well- it was meant to be 'an ask and answer my own question'!

Comment: ah, missed that. Good one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When on the command-line it is certainly possible to do what you want, although the syntax of readline can be confusing: see the appendix at the end of the article for a short list of examples.

You can use the GNU readline library and create some macros and place them in your `~/.inputrc`. Then you will be able to insert arbitrary strings into the terminal when you press a key combination. As noted in [the bash manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/bash.1.html) :

> In addition to command names, readline allows keys to be bound to a string that is inserted when the key is pressed (a macro).
>   The  syntax  for  controlling  key bindings in the inputrc file is simple.  All that is required is the name of the command or the text of a macro and a key sequence to which it should be bound. The name may be specified in one of two ways: as a symbolic key name, possibly with Meta- or Control- prefixes, or as a key sequence.

Be careful when assigning shortcut combinations to arbitrary strings, as many keybindings are already set whether you are using Bash's emacs or vi mode (in addition to the independent tty bindings). See `bind -P` for a list of currently bound Bash shortcuts, and `stty -a` for the others in use.

You just need to place your macros in `~/.inputrc` (create it if it doesn't exist), and add, for example:

```
Control-o: "U+16a1"
```

but it's probably **better** to use, for example, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>instead, because most ctrl and a single letter combinations are already bound:

```
"\e\C-o": "U+16a1"
```

Then restart terminal and use your key combinations to place the string at the cursor's position. There are many complex and more interesting possibilities; experiment and you'll find the macros very useful when you have to repeat various things a lot. List your currently assigned macros with `bind -s`.

---

List of examples for reference (don't use these as some will already be assigned): see `bind -P`:

```
"\e\C-k": "string"  # ctrl+alt+k
"\ey": "string" # alt+y
"\C-w": "string" # ctrl+w
"\C-x\C-e": "string" # ctrl+x, ctrl+e
```

See `man 3 readline` for more information and [the Ubuntu manpages online](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man3/readline.3readline.html).

Comment: Is there a list of possible symbolic key names?